# What am I doing wrong? I need Springboot to not ask for login at a specific url

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an application with sprint boot that requires login, what I want to achieve is that if they enter a specific URL, it does not ask for their username or password.

This page will be an external form that will be filled out by the general public.

What happens to me is that if I enter the URL it redirects me to the login page, if I am logged in it takes me to the page I want, but if not, it redirects me to the login page.

So if the client enters the url http://domain/FormClient

I want the application not to ask for login.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL = "/login";
private static final String LOGIN_FAILURE_URL = "/login?error";
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";
private static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL = "/login";

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from users where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from users where username=?")

    ;
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/FormClient").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL)
            .failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL)
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL)}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            "/VAADIN/**",
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/robots.txt",
            "/sms/",
            "/manifest.webmanifest",
            "/sw.js",
            "/offline.html",
            "/icons/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/styles/**",
            "/h2-console/**");
}
```

and the listener class is like this

/* if not authenticated and the URL is different to Login, redirect to Login
I already tried commenting on this line but it doesn't work*/

```
@Component 
public class ConfigureUIServiceInitListener implements VaadinServiceInitListener {

    @Override
    public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent event) {
        event.getSource().addUIInitListener(uiEvent -> { 
            final UI ui = uiEvent.getUI();
            ui.addBeforeEnterListener(this::authenticateNavigation);
        });
    }

    private void authenticateNavigation(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
        if (!LoginView.class.equals(event.getNavigationTarget())
            && !SecurityUtils.isUserLoggedIn()) { 

            event.rerouteTo(LoginView.class);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Can you help me?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Side note: Don't reconfigure defaults. All of the constants you created just replace the default settings with the same thing. Also, don't disable CSRF on a cookie-login application; that's exactly where it's needed.

Comment: Try removing the `@EnableWebSecurity`; Boot already turns this on, and doing this prevents the Boot auto-configuration from helping you.

Comment: So, what modifications would you make to the code to make it work? @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: remove the `VaadinServiceInitListener` let spring security handle the security, nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vaadin there is a class that implement a Interface.

I just put this code:

```
    @Component 
public class ConfigureUIServiceInitListener  implements VaadinServiceInitListener {

@Override
public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent event) {
    event.getSource().addUIInitListener(uiEvent -> {
        final UI ui = uiEvent.getUI();
        ui.addBeforeEnterListener(this::authenticateNavigation);
    });
}

private void authenticateNavigation(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    if (!LoginView.class.equals(event.getNavigationTarget())
        && !SecurityUtils.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        if(event.getNavigationTarget().getName().endsWith("FormClient"))
        {
            System.out.println("Retorna porque es FormClient");
            return;
        }
        if(event.getNavigationTarget().getName().endsWith("FormClientCertified"))
        {
            System.out.println("Retorna porque es FormClientCertified");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("redirecciona ["+event.getNavigationTarget().getName());
            event.rerouteTo(LoginView.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Now is working, so when someone ask for URL ending in FormClient, it doesn't redirect to login.